# Using Python 2.7 to complete webform

Tags: python

Could the kind Python experts out there please tell me if there's a way to complete a webform and submit the results using a python script for version 2.7 from Windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) or [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/2.7.0).

Comment: Thanks for the link, Hisagr , but I think the link you supplied is for beautifulsoup 4.  The version of Python 2.7 , I have only works with Beautiful Soup 3 .